# HTML Element Stretch in One Direction?

Tags: css

What if I wanted to have a HTML element only fill in one direction? Normally width:100% just fills the whole page so what if I wanted to have a element end one direction and never end in the other direction. I made a small example to explain what I mean.

I tried to think of some methods of doing it so I could share them here and be more useful but I couldn't think of anyway how to do this.

[image]

Comment: can you show me in jsfiddle or provide your html, css code

Comment: `position: absolute` + `right`.

Comment: There is no concept of "forever"; all lengths are a finite number (either something that translates to a pixel value, or a percentage of the parent's dimension).

Comment: If you are talking about having a constantly scrolling horizontal page, this would only be achievable with code (i.e. JavaScript) (constantly repositioning an element off-screen), and would be clunky at that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this any use?

```
.funny-box{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  right: 80%;
 }
```

Or if you want to show more on the same row of the page.

```
<div class="special-row">
  <div class="funny-box"></div>
  <div class="regular-box"></div>
</div>

.special-row{
  position: relative;
}

.funny-box{
  width: 100%; /** or any width you want, but it needs a width **/
  position: absolute;
  right: 80%;
}
.regular-box{
  margin-left: 20%; /* flow normally, leave room for .funny-box */
}
```

The important thing to remember is that .funny-box will need an explicit width.
If you wanted you could use javascript to always make sure it at least reaches the far left edge of the window.

In jQuery (other libraries, as well as the option of not using libraries, are available), you could do something like this:

```
$('.funny-box').width($(window).width());
```

This will mean the box is always the width of the window, and as such, it will always go beyond the left-hand side of the window, if you position it the way you propose. 
As Jon quite rightly points out, there is no such thing as "forever" in css, but you can give users the *impression* that it goes on forever using this method.

I recommend an inner div inside .funny-box, floated to the right and cleared, so your stuff is always on screen.